# Resolving Promise Outside

Tags: typescript, promise

I am attempting to get access to the `resolve` and `reject` arguments of a `promise` so that I can resolve/reject it from another method.

Here's a sample of the implementation:

```js
class TestClass {
  public readonly initialized: Promise<void> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("initialized");
    this.resolver = resolve;
    console.log("this.resolver", this.resolver);
    this.rejector = reject;
  });
  private resolver: (value?: void | PromiseLike<void>) => void;
  private rejector: (value?: void | PromiseLike<void>) => void;
  public constructor() {
    console.log("constructor");
    console.log("this.resolver", this.resolver);
  }
  public load() {
    // Do stuff and call `this.resoler()` or `this.rejector()`.
  }
}
```

I am doing this so that I can wait until some internals are ready to mark the class instance as initialized:

```js
public async componentDidMount() {
  await testClass.initialized;
  // Do stuff.
}
```

The problem I am running in to that depending on where I test run this code, `this.resolver` remains `undefined`.

Running this code in my React app using TypeScript 3.7.3 I get:

```
initialized
this.resolver ƒ () { [native code] }
constructor
this.resolver undefined
```

However, running it in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) against the highest version 3.7.2 I get the expect result:

```
initialized
this.resolver ƒ () { [native code] }
constructor
this.resolver ƒ () { [native code] }
```

I am stumped as to why `this.resolver` is `undefined` in my React app, but the same code works fine in online playgrounds.

Comment: Is `TestClass` a React component?

Comment: @Eldar No, `TestClass` is not a React component.

Comment: Perform initialisations in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have a `initialized` method, but just run it inside the constructor:

```js
class TestClass {
  public readonly initialized: Promise<void>;
  private resolver: (value?: void | PromiseLike<void>) => void;
  private rejector: (value?: void | PromiseLike<void>) => void;

  public constructor() {
    this.initialized = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.resolver = resolve;
      this.rejector = reject;
    });
  }

  public load() {
    // Do stuff and call `this.resoler()` or `this.rejector()`.
  }
}
```

Comment: Moving it to the constructor fixes the problem. I'm still left scratching my head as to why the code works in some TypeScript interpreters, and doesn't in others. Seems to me it should be valid everywhere.

Comment: Maybe older/different ES lib being used in tsconfig?